# Wrong data type conversion after melt

Tags: r, data.table, melt

I get a `numeric` to `integer64` type conversion after melting a `data.table` object in R.

Given the file `stats.txt`, tab separated:

```
id  x             y
A   283726709252  0.1
B   288604342155  0.2
C   329048184196  0.3
D   192107948937  0.4
```

I want to read it into a `data.table` and *melt* it. So:

```
library(data.table)
stats<- fread('stats.txt')

 stats
   id            x   y
1:  A 283726709252 0.1
2:  B 288604342155 0.2
3:  C 329048184196 0.3
4:  D 192107948937 0.4

str(stats)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  4 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ id: chr  "A" "B" "C" "D"
 $ x :integer64 283726709252 288604342155 329048184196 192107948937 
 $ y : num  0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

So far so good. Now if I melt it, I get the *y* variable converted from numeric to integer64:

```
xm<- melt.data.table(data= stats, id.vars= 'id')

xm
   id variable               value
1:  A        x        283726709252
2:  B        x        288604342155
3:  C        x        329048184196
4:  D        x        192107948937
5:  A        y 4591870180066957722
6:  B        y 4596373779694328218
7:  C        y 4599075939470750515
8:  D        y 4600877379321698714

str(xm)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  8 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ id      : chr  "A" "B" "C" "D" ...
 $ variable: Factor w/ 2 levels "x","y": 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2
 $ value   :integer64 283726709252 288604342155 329048184196 192107948937 4591870180066957722 4596373779694328218 4599075939470750515 4600877379321698714 
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.4/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_2.2.1       data.table_1.10.4-3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.4.1   colorspace_1.3-2 scales_0.5.0     lazyeval_0.2.0   plyr_1.8.4       gtable_0.2.0     tibble_1.3.3     Rcpp_0.12.12     grid_3.4.1       rlang_0.1.1      munsell_0.4.3
```

Comment: Your x and y variables are reshaped into a single variable. Since your x-variable is origibally an integer64 variable after reading the file, your new variable gets also converterd to integer64. Keep in mind that a column in R can only contain one type, it's not possible that half is numeric and the rest integer64 in one column

Comment: @docendo discimus Thanks for replying. Sure, after melting you have to force everything into one data type. I'm just a bit surprised that this happens without any warning when clearly column y gets mangled... For the record, `fread('stats.txt', integer64= 'numeric')` fixes the problem provided one is happy to convert the big integers to numeric with possible loss of precision.

Comment: Yeah, data.table will combine vectors without warning when their storage modes match, generally, taking the other vector attributes from the first vector. Compare ..  `data.table(id = 1:2)[, if (id == 1) as.integer64("283726709252") else 0.1, by=id]` vs `data.table(id = 1:2)[, if (id == 2) as.integer64("283726709252") else 0.1, by=id]`. Same thing can happen with factors and integers (which also share a storage mode).

Comment: Perhaps you can also workaround this issue by changing the unit of the large numbers.